# cannot connect to meteor with android-ddp after deploying the meteor app

Tags: android, meteor, ddp, mup

I was using `ws://example.com:3000/websocket` for connecting `Android-ddp` to meteor app. Meteor was runing on `example.com:3000`. It was working fine.

Now I deployed the app using `mup` on the same URL, `example.com` and `port: 3000`. I am able to access the app on browser but can't get it working with `Android-ddp`. It just won't connect.

What I might be doing wrong?

Comment: you own example.com ? that's great! :)

Comment: try to deployed your application again, then restart the container manually

Answer (score 0):

Analyze the logs on both server and client side to obtain more details on the problem.